# Should I use WHICH or BY WHICH?

Tags: adjectives, clauses

"Photosynthesis is the process ---- green plants and certain other organisms use the energy of light to convert carbon dioxide and water into the simple glucose."

It seems "which" is more correct. But answer is "by which". Can you explain to me?

Other question:
"The materials **from which** soil form is called parent material."

In here, the sentence seems incomplete to me because of "from which".
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look up the word "by" and you'll understand more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Photosynthesis is the process **by which** plants generate glucose

is correct. The reason why is that it's equivalent to

> Photosynthesis is the process **which** plants generate glucose **by**

Which is in turn incorrect if you drop the "by" at the end because

> Plants generate glucose **by** a process

is correct, and

> Plants generate glucose a process

is not.

Comment: add a citation to your reasoning to ensure your answer's viability.

Comment: Welp, my source of this is my high school English teacher, so there you have it....